# Material multiselect not displaying item list

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm setting up a stackblitz to test some select options.  My end goal is to have the same control as in the angular examples, but I want to use two way binding to have my check selections be persisted and displayed on page load instead of using a form.  I'm following the example here (https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples#select-multiple) and have the exact same code in my stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b5vtjl?file=src/app/app.component.ts), but my list does not display.

What am I missing?

HTML

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{
      topping
    }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS FILE

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  toppings = new FormControl();
  toppingList: string[] = [
    'Extra cheese',
    'Mushroom',
    'Onion',
    'Pepperoni',
    'Sausage',
    'Tomato',
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import BrowserAnimationsModule in app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({   imports: [BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule,FormsModule, MatSelectModule, ReactiveFormsModule],   declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],  bootstrap: [AppComponent], })
```